# C# - Read attributes from XML with sub Xmlns

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Newbi on XML. 
Trying to read the Text attribute from all DisplayName:s. Think my problem is near the Rule element. Is ther a way to solve my problem? Thanks in advance! //Magnus

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<AppMgmtDigest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenterConfigurationManager/2009/AppMgmtDigest">
  <DeploymentType >
    <Requirements>
      <Rule xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules">
        <Annotation>
          <DisplayName Text="Primary device Equals True"/>
        </Annotation>
      </Rule>
      <Rule xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules">
        <Annotation>
          <DisplayName Text="Operating system One of {All Windows 10 (64-bit)}"/>
        </Annotation>
      </Rule>
    </Requirements>
  </DeploymentType>
</AppMgmtDigest>





XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(SDMPackageXML);

XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("msbld","http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenterConfigurationManager/2009/AppMgmtDigest");
ns.AddNamespace("msbldr","http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules");

XmlNodeList nodlist = xml.SelectNode("/msbld:AppMgmtDigest/msbld:DeploymentType/msbld:Requirements/msbldr:Rule", ns/@Text);
```

Comment: Looks like reasonable starting point. Clarifying what exact problem you have with this code would help.

Comment: Hi Alexei! The problem is that nodlist Count is 0. I'm expecting that Count is 2.  <Rule xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules">
        <Annotation>
          <DisplayName Text="Primary device Equals True"/>
        </Annotation>
      </Rule>
      <Rule xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules">
        <Annotation>
          <DisplayName Text="Operating system One of {All Windows 10 (64-bit)}"/>
        </Annotation>
      </Rule>

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine(); //skip the identification line with utf-16
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);

            List<string> text = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "DisplayName").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Text")).ToList();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a typo in the namespace: `Systems` in xml, `System` in C#.

Secondly, your code does not compile. Before you post it, correct the obvious errors.

Try this please:

```
// Correct typo
ns.AddNamespace("msbldr",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules");

XmlNodeList nodelst = xml.SelectNodes(
    "/msbld:AppMgmtDigest/msbld:DeploymentType/msbld:Requirements/msbldr:Rule//@Text", ns);
```

Also, your xpath may specify the exact path to the desired attribute:

```
"/msbld:AppMgmtDigest/msbld:DeploymentType/msbld:Requirements/msbldr:Rule/msbldr:Annotation/msbldr:DisplayName/@Text"
```